# Issues with integrating Okta with iOS webview

Tags: ios, okta

We are trying to integrate Okta with an iOS native app using webview and Okta service is not redirecting to the authenticated URL. The same setup is working fine in Android app. Are there any specific settings that we need to add to iOS web view?

Answer (score 1):

**Okta Open ID Connect**

For okta Login use:
`pod 'OktaOidc'`

configure your Okta dashboard apply according in below plist file

create `Okta.plist` file inside your project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>issuer</key>
    <string>https://xyz.okta.com</string>
    <key>clientId</key>
    <string>wOe*******86wySs</string>
    <key>redirectUri</key>
    <string>com.x***z.okta:/callback</string>
    <key>logoutRedirectUri</key>
    <string>com.x***z.okta:/logout</string>
    <key>scopes</key>
    <string>openid profile offline_access</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

import the SDK `import OktaOidc`

Declare

```
    var authStateManager: OktaOidcStateManager? {
        didSet {
            oldValue?.clear()
            authStateManager?.writeToSecureStorage()
        }
    }
```

on Button Click:

```
    @IBAction func loginButtonAct(_ sender: Any) {
        self.oktaOidc?.signInWithBrowser(from: self) { stateManager, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Error
                authStateManager = nil
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.alert(titleStr: "Sorry", messageStr: "Something went wrong, Please try again.")
                return
            }
            // Success
            print("*************: Logged In Succesfully :*************")
            authStateManager = stateManager
            print("\(String(describing: authStateManager?.accessToken!))")
            print("\(String(describing: authStateManager?.refreshToken!))")
        }
    }
```

don't forget to store the authStateManger.

Answer (score 0):

Krishna,

Could you please provide more details on what you are trying to do? Please also provide details such as whether MFA is enabled (which one) and error messages if any.

Thanks,
Chandra.

Comment: We are trying to authenticate a user using Okta SSO using web view from native app. Okta website is authenticating the user but is not redirecting to the correct url or not passing the authentication information back to the calling web app. MFA is not enabled. This has been troubling us for the past 1 month and our customers are very unhappy with the product. We need immediate solution. If you can provide an email to discuss this further, it will be easier to share account credentials.

Comment: Can you also tell me the best way to integrate Okta in iOS? Is there iOS SDK or is webview the only option?

Comment: Since there is no MFA involved you can use Okta's Session API: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/rest/sessions.html. Post valid credentials to receive a cookie token.